# ¿Se puede repetir un formulario reactivo de Angular dinamicamente?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formularios

Muy buenas a todos. Los pongo en situación. Tengo un formulario reactivo de angular, donde únicamente hay tres campos a llenar, una fecha de inicio, una fecha fin, y un porcentaje.
El problema es que el usuario debería completar ese formulario tantas veces como subcategorías haya seleccionado. Adjunto una foto para un mejor entendimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En definitiva, debo poder repetir ese formulario reactivo de Angular tantas veces como elementos haya en mi array de subcategoriasSeleccionadas.
Es esto posible?

Muchas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: Y por qué no conviertes ese formulario en un componente y lo creas con un ngFor directamente?? Sería lo más fácil

Comment: Entiendo, pero mi idea seria que se muestre de a un formulario a la vez.. seria, una vez terminado de completar uno, al apretar el boton, pasar al que sigue.. no se si me explico.

Comment: Entonces te sería más fácil usar el mismo formulario, simplemente recoger los valores, guardarlos en un array y limpiar el formulario para que se inserten los siguientes datos

Answer (score 0):

Esto es posible usando [FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms).

Ejemplo:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  fb: FormBuilder;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.fb = fb;
  }
  
 ngOnInit(): void {

  exampleForm = this.fb.group({
  subCategorias: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      fechaInicio: [''],
      fechaFin: [''],
      porcentaje: ['']
    })
  ])
 }
```

Con esto, el formulario `exampleForm` tiene un `FormArray` llamado `subCategorias` al que se le pueden agregar dinámicamente más formularios reactivos.

Deberías añadir el código de tu componente para adecuar esta respuesta a tu necesidad.

De todas formas te recomiendo que leas la documentación de angular https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms